# Problem of Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an error while compiling showing that a class doesn't have a property when I call it from the component, even if the call works well.

This is the class:

```
    export declare class MessageService {
    private messageSource;
    private clearSource;
    messageObserver: import("rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<Message | Message[]>;
    clearObserver: import("rxjs/internal/Observable").Observable<string>;
   public  add(message: Message): void;
   public addAll(messages: Message[]): void;
    clear(key?: string): void;
}
```

and this is where I call it from the component:

```
showSuccess(details) {
    this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', life: 5000, summary: 'Success Message', detail: details });        
}
```

Compiled with warnings.

```
ERROR in C:/Users/..../webapp/app/entities/asset/asset-update.component.ts(555,29):
TS2339: Property 'add' does not exist on type 'MessageService'.
```

this is messageService.js :

```
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var core_1 = require("@angular/core");
var rxjs_1 = require("rxjs");
var MessageService = /** @class */ (function () {
    function MessageService() {
        this.messageSource = new rxjs_1.Subject();
        this.clearSource = new rxjs_1.Subject();
        this.messageObserver = this.messageSource.asObservable();
        this.clearObserver = this.clearSource.asObservable();
    }
    MessageService.prototype.add = function (message) {
        if (message) {
            this.messageSource.next(message);
        }
    };
    MessageService.prototype.addAll = function (messages) {
        if (messages && messages.length) {
            this.messageSource.next(messages);
        }
    };
    MessageService.prototype.clear = function (key) {
        this.clearSource.next(key || null);
    };
    MessageService = __decorate([
        core_1.Injectable()
    ], MessageService);
    return MessageService;
}());
exports.MessageService = MessageService;
//# sourceMappingURL=messageservice.js.map
```

Comment: How did you provided MessageService class in your component? Does your service have @Injectable() decorator?  Please give us more information.

Comment: Please show the component's `construct` and the component's providers.

Comment: I call it in the  asset.module.ts , and I put it as a provider, and in the component I called the service in the constructor

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a regular class, then you need to instantiate it like this:

```
public messageService: MessageService = new MessageService();
```

If this is service decorated with @Injcetable() you need to register this service to module, and use it by providing it in constructor of your component like this:

```
constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {...}
```

and then all properties of class that are public will be visible.

EDIT:
Maybe you should have implementation of your add method inside MessageService class. Right now it just looks like this:

```
public  add(message: Message): void;
```

instead of this you should try:

```
public add(message: Message): void {
    // do something with you message like this...
    this.messages.push(message);
}
```

Comment: It is in the constructor , you can see , I updated the post, but I didnt make the decorateur of Injectable() ,  The problem is when I run the project , the call works well

Comment: I saw the edit, yes. But now did you decorate it, does it work after decoration?

Comment: maybe is the problem that this is a class and you dont have an implementation for add method... public  add(message: Message): void;

Comment: I didn't understand , I call it from the the component and it works but the error always appears , however how can I hide this error

Comment: I added the implementation (messageservice.js) in the post